# How to show terms that haven't been selected in a view?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a vocab called 'Mounting Options' and I have selected a certain number of terms from this vocab on each Camera node type.

The ones I have selected show on the front-end but I want to show terms that I haven't selected in a separate field.

I can use views reference or a block on the camera node type but I can't figure out how to make the view to show terms that haven't been selected on that node.

Then on the camera node it will have a view block/field called **Mounting Options That Don't Work**

Then under this, just a list of titles of the terms that weren't selected in the previous mounting options field.

Comment: Drupal version?

Comment: I am using drupal 8